# How to put a filter on the tables that are joined in the aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

Here is the query. I have applied filters on type and description fields.

```
    this.issue.aggregate
        (
            [
                {
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        "from":"users",
                        "localField": "userId",
                        "foreignField": "userId",
                        "as":"user"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        "from":"products",
                        "localField": "productId",
                        "foreignField": "productId",
                        "as":"product"
                    }
                },
                {"$unwind":"$user"},
                {"$unwind":"$product"},
                {
                    "$project":
                    {
                        "_id":1,
                        "issueId":1,
                        "status":1,
                        "type":1,
                        "description":1,
                        "created":1,
                        "pictures":1,
                        "userId":1,
                        "productId":1,
                        "user.userId":1,
                        "user.name":1,
                        "product.productId":1,
                        "product.name":1,
                        "product.brand":1
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $or:
                        [
                            {"type": { $regex: searchTerm }},
                            {"description": { $regex: searchTerm }}
                        ]
                    }
                },
            ]
        );
```

I want to put a regex on **user.name** and **product.name**. How to do that? Putting it inside the $match operator doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I had a hard time posting this as Stack Overflow keeps saying too much code.

Comment: * Putting it inside the $match operator doesn't seem to work* : Can you give us your attempt ? what is the issue ? cause it shouldn't fail as it's my assumption..

Comment: {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $or:
                        [
                            {"type": { $regex: searchTerm }},
                            {"description": { $regex: searchTerm }},
                             {"user.name": { $regex: searchTerm }},
                        ]
                    }
                },


I Tried this ... didn't work

Comment: what do you've in `user.name` & what do you've in `searchTerm` ?

Comment: both are string fields. The search term has the text searched for.

Comment: Can we see a sample document or two?

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do: https://mongoplayground.net/p/V4svm3F5zPB, which seems to work with strings.

Comment: @Joe yes ... in place of "user" in the regex am searching for a partial word. Basically I have a search box which onChange hits an api which runs this mongo query. It checks for a partial match on type and description fields. But it doesn't work with the user field somehow.

Comment: could we see example values of something not working?